# ffmpeg how to record a specific window (even when not visible)

Tags: ffmpeg, recording

I want to record a specific window even when its not visible(another window is above it) using ffmpeg
is it possible?
if so how?

Comment: I am not sure it can be done, because window is not necessarily refreshed, if it is not shown. Window receives a paint event when is it visible. When it is not visible, that event is not sent and window is not redrawn. There is no use to draw window's content, if it is no one can see it. Why using CPU for drawing something that is not going to be visible.

Comment: But obs studio is able to record  a window even when its not visible so i think it is possible maybe not using ffmpeg @nobody